# NavigationBar is not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uinavigationbar

**Explanation:** I have a viewcontroller that contains a NavigationBar and a UIWebView. The webview is set to full screen in the .m file. On the viewcontroller, the navigationbar is arranged to the front.

**What happens:** When I run the app, the only thing that is visible is the webview (full screen) but the navigation bar is not there.

**What's suppose to happen:** This is self-explanatory but the navigationbar is suppose to be at the top with webview under it.

**What it looks like**

[image]

**.m file**

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController2

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
      UIWebView *webview2=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,  self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
    NSString *url2=@"http://bithumor.co/server/trending/index1.php";
    NSURL *nsurl2=[NSURL URLWithString:url2];

    NSURLRequest *nsrequest2=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl2];

    [webview2 loadRequest:nsrequest2];

    webview2.scrollView.bounces = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:webview2];

@end
```

**.h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController

@end
```

**Issue/Question:** The navigationbar isn't visible, how can this be fixed so both the webview and navigationbar are visible?

Comment: can you show us the storyboard?

Comment: @T_77 edited my question

Comment: also show us the view heirrachy

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vlrQp.png - front being the webview

Comment: delete the line UIWebView *webview2.......

Comment: and just connect the webview2 to its outlet in storyboard, and use self.webview2  loadrequest

Comment: I removed the iboutlet @property

Comment: then set the frame size properly and dont set it to self.view.frame which covers the full screen.

Comment: try CGRectMake(0, 0, 200,200) and see if it still covers the navigation bar

Comment: I covers half of the nav bar and 1/3 of the screen vertically.

Comment: then try this (0,50,200,200)

Comment: (x position,y positipon, width , height ) , you can modify these according to your need. (0,0) starts from the top left of the screen

Comment: @T_77 but then it will only fit perfectly on certain screens (iPhone4s)

Comment: you need to set constriants so that , it will be resized for all screens.

Comment: use masonry to set the constraints

Comment: Sure this is not just really simple and that because your controller is not a navigation controller that the nav bar is just a view and you have put the web view right in front of it? Use this instead to add you web view to the back and see what happens: `[self.view insertSubview:webview2 atIndex:0];`

Comment: Life would be so much easier if you did not allocate objects programmatically, but used Storyboard to define layout and constraints. When programming, it is very easy to miss out on abstract concepts that @Larcerax has isolated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I can replicate what you may be experiencing, and I've wrapped up two projects so that you can see them. Here's some screen shots, but first the code I'm using is your code in this fashion:

1. Create single page application
2. Replace the view did load with your view did load

Here's the results of using your code with a navigation bar with your code and with a navigation bar like you said:

You can download this project here: http://www18.zippyshare.com/v/DXi9wySi/file.html

**Expanded Layout (same result you have):**

[image]

**Storyboard Layout:**

[image]

So, given the above screenshots and the navigation bar being placed behind the we web view is due, in part to the fact that I don't have a navigation controller that is holding my view controller so the placement of a navigation bar is entirely useless and doesn't show up on the screen. In addition, the navigation bar wouldn't even do anything if it did show up since there's no navigation controller in the hierarchy.

Now, given this first example, here's a correction.

This is the same as the layout as above but the difference is that I've rooted the view controller in a navigation controller .. everything remains the same and in fact, I didn't even add a navigation bar to the storyboard since this is auto generated by the rooting of a view controller of a navigation controller.

You can download this project: http://www41.zippyshare.com/v/aXRlAT3a/file.html

**Expanded Layout:**

[image]

**Storyboard Layout:**

[image]

So, the difference here, again is that I'm rooting the view controller in a navigation controller.

**Conclusion:**

It could very well be the case that the problem you are experiencing is totally different from the problem I've explained above, but using your code, I was able to achieve the same result that you have in my first example. In my second example, I was able to use a web view, exactly as you show with your code, and I in fact DO have a navigation bar on this second example. The only thing I changed in the second example was rooting the view controller in a navigation controller.

Comment: So will I have to do that for EVERY SINGLE viewcontroller?

Comment: @PHPWebDev101 if you need help understanding how this works with multiple view controllers then please let me know, i can create a new project with multiple view contorllers hooked up

Comment: Well done @Larcerax, and props for using Storyboard & Autolayout in **IB**.

Answer (score 2):

## 0 Lines of Code Solution

Do the `UIWebview` creation in the `Storyboard`: layout, constraints, navigation bar from Navigation Controller, title, referencing outlets, delegates, all of it. Every bit of setup implemented at the resource level will remove lines of code, potential bugs, testing, headaches and frustration.

[image]

**Entire Class**

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    NSString *url2=@"https://google.com";
    NSURL *nsurl2=[NSURL URLWithString:url2];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest2=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl2];
    self.webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    [self.webView loadRequest:nsrequest2];
}

@end
```

---

The solution becomes language agnostic, and works equally well in **Swift** & **Obj-C**.

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-32277486) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-32277486).

Answer (score 2):

debug your views and check whether u r root view controller is navigation controller or not. 
also check self.navigationController == nil

Answer (score 1):

Is the `ViewController2` actually in a `UINavigationController` or had the `UINavigationBar` been placed into the view in the `Storyboard`?

If you have just dragged the `UINavigationBar` into the view in the `Storyboard`, and then in the `viewDidLoad` method you are adding the `UIWebView` (with a frame of the full `UIView` of the `ViewController2`), then of course you will not see the `UINavigationBar` because it is being covered by the `UIWebView`.

If the `ViewController2` is actually in a `UINavigationController`, then I will need more details to find the problem.

**EDIT: A (possibly) unrelated problem:**

In your `Storyboard`, you already have placed a `UIWebView`, which I am guessing you are connecting to the `IBOutlet` of `webView2`.

Why are you instantiating -another- `UIWebView` in your `viewDidLoad` code? You already have one and can just reference it instead of creating a new one for seemingly no reason.

Comment: The view controller2 is not in a UINavigationController. The UINavigationBar was placed in the viewcontroller.

Comment: im sure that is what making the webview cover the screen.

Comment: If you comment out the following line, do you still see the `UINavigationBar` covered?

    `[self.view addSubview:webview2];`

Comment: No, but now the webview is not loading and/or is not visible

Comment: btw i took out the  iboutlet for the webview (before commenting out the self.view) and it still loaded the webpage

Comment: Yes of course it still loaded the webpage because you are not telling the `UIWebView` that is connected via `IBOulet` to load the webpage. 

The real solution is to remove the line where you do `UIWebView *webview2=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,  self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];`

and instead of referencing  `webview2` put `self. webview2`

Also, reconnect the `IBOutlet`in the Storyboard incase you forget.

Comment: No, I did that BEFORE you told me to comment out self.view

Comment: Can you tell me why you are instantiating a new `UIWebView` when you already have one in the storyboard?

Comment: I don't know but i took out the iboutlet so there's only this  - UIWebView *webview2=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88228/discussion-between-will-and-php-web-dev-101).

Answer (score 1):

Short and simple:

1. Most likely that you are using a simulated metrics to display a navigation bar view in storyboard. Simulated metics section parameters are only used to check how your interface will look on the different devices with different resolutions. They have no direct impact on the runtime view.

[image]

2. To make your view controller have a navigation bar view on top (view controller) in general case it should have a UINavigationController as a parent VC (as was shown by @SwiftArchitect).

Answer (score 0):

To those of you that none of the above worked for, I have just found another issue that can cause the navigation bar not to show. If you have already added a navigation controller and the navigation bar isn't showing, then this could apply to you if you have a similar set up to me. I have a login vC which then links through the navigation controller to a news feed. If you set the news feed to Is Initial View Controller in the attributes inspector, then the navigation bar will not show. If however, you reach the news feed via the login page (i.e. login) and you are therefore routed there by the navigation controller, then the navigation bar will show. This means that if you want the navigation bar to show, don't use "Is Initial View Controller".